# Convert list of hex numbers into string

Tags: python, string, list, hex

I have a list of hex numbers:

```
[0xaa4d, 0x4643, 0x3353, 0x074c, 0x4854, 0x4138]
```

My goal is to convert it to something like this:

```
aa4d46433353074c48544138
```

What I've tried:

```
list = [0xaa4d, 0x4643, 0x3353, 0x074c, 0x4854, 0x4138]
string = ''.join('%02x' % i for i in list)
```

The output is:

```
aa4d4643335374c48544138
```

So, it's seems like OK, but, as we see, the output is somehow different from what I need, because `0x074c` converts to `74c` instead of `074c`

I've also tried this:

```
l = [0xaa4d, 0x4643, 0x3353, 0x074c, 0x4854, 0x4138]

s = ''.join('{:02x}'.format(i) for i in l)

print(s)
```

This still gives me wrong results. I've also tried different numbers at `'{:02x}'` & `'%02x'`, but still no luck.

My thoughts that converting hex to string removes leading zeros, but I don't know how to do it right.

My question is how to convert `0x074c` to `074c` without losing leading zero. Cause my code gives me `74c` instead.
What am I missing here?

Comment: `"".join(f"{i:04x}" for i in hexlist)` will do the trick. You need the `04` in the formatting sequence to guarantee you get all 4 bytes of each hex digit.

Comment: @MattDMo your suggestion is correct! 
I've got this string: 
`aa4d46433353074c48544138`
Could you please explain the meaning of `f` right after join? 
I've tried `'{:02x}'` and it wasn't any helpful.

Comment: The `f` means the following string is a formatted string or f-string. They were introduced in Python 3.6. You can read all about them in the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals) and [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings).

Comment: @MattDMo got you. If it possible, could you please explain how to do the same on Python 2.7. Cause unfortunately my project is currently on 2.7 ver.

Comment: `".join("%04x" % i for i in hexlist)` should do it. `"".join("{:04x}".format(i) for i in hexlist)` will also work, depending on whether you want to use old- or new-style formatting.